# How do I locate the text input box on Huggingspace using Selenium + Chrome?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

I want to locate the text input box on https://huggingface.co/spaces/damo-vilab/modelscope-text-to-video-synthesis
And enter a prompt into it.

I have tried locating via XPATH

```
# Locate the text input element and enter the prompt
text_input = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="prompt-text-input"]/label/input'))
)

# Click the text input element before entering the prompt
text_input.click()
text_input.clear()
text_input.send_keys(video_prompt)
```

and via CSS Selector:

```
# Locate the text input element and enter the prompt
text_input = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#prompt-text-input > label > input"))
)

# Click the text input element before entering the prompt
text_input.click()
text_input.clear()
text_input.send_keys(video_prompt)
```

RESULT: The program times out, because it's unable to find the text input element.

I think I have the correct version of the chromedriver, so I don't think that's the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its part on an iframe thats why you are not not able to access it, you need to first switch tot he iframe and then access the input box
[image]

Use below code to switch to frame and then enter the data it should work

```
driver.get("https://huggingface.co/spaces/damo-vilab/modelscope-text-to-video-synthesis")

frame = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//iframe[@title="Space app"]')
driver.switch_to.frame(frame)

text_input = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="prompt-text-input"]/label/input'))
)

text_input.send_keys("data")
```